# hive export to pipe delimited file

Tags: hive, export

How to change the below command so that i can export the output file as a pipe delimited file.

```
shellcommand='''hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false; use hivedb1; %s; ' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > %s '''%(selectqry,'path/outputfile.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the hive output with linux redirection. The standard output is resultset. You can concat the output columns with concat_ws function. Like:

```
CMD=`hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true; set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false; use hivedb1; select concat_ws('|',col_1,col_2,col_3) from tbl" 1> output_file.txt 2> log.txt`
```

Comment: Yes. but my columns count are dynamic.so this would be very difficult. But i found the solution. Instead of **sed 's/[\t]/,/g'** use **sed 's/[\t]/|/g'**  . Anyway thanks